# Rails 5.1 Installing ActiveAdmin without Devise and a custom User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

So I have a question, about using ActiveAdmin without Devise, the documentation is not clear on this for my needs and I see a lot of people not answering this question clearly. And to be clear, I am using Rails 5.1

To install without using devise you run

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
```

In my case, I already have a User class and my own authentication. The docs say:

*If you want to use an existing user class, provide it as an argument:*

```
rails g active_admin:install User
```

this is where the confusion for me lies. Since, I already have a User class and DO NOT want to use Devise, and the generator above does install Devise, would I run

```
rails g active_admin:install User --skip-users
```

or

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
```

Comment: I believe that if you use active admin without Devise**, you wouldnt have user support, atleast not built-in, so it would be useless to define a user class. You shoud use 

rails g active_admin:install --skip-users

Comment: I am using Rails... What I am looking for is to not use Devise, a Rails authentication gem...

Comment: Sorry, meant devise, updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation states:

> After installing the gem, you need to run the generator. Here are your options:
>
> If you don’t want to use Devise, run it with --skip-users:
>
> ```
> rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
> ```

Further reading:

https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html#setting-up-active-admin

After that create your own `User` model, as described in the docs. You can handle authentication as described here:

https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#authentication

Normally it incorporates defining some controller method like `authenticate_admin_user!`.